# Multidimensional multiple knapsack? How to distribute items into containers

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I am looking for a problem description which covers the following optimization problem:

- Given a small finit set of items, each with four dimensions (width, height, length, weight)
- Given an infinit amount of containers, each constrained by four dimensions (max width, max height, max length, max weight) and an assosiated cost (there is an infinit amout of containers available but only a small set of different classes)

How to distribute the set of items into containers so that the sum of cost is minimal?

Since I have multiple containers, multiple knapsack looked promising. But each item does not only have one dimension assosiated but multiple, so I thought of multidimensional knapsack. But the dimensions in multidimensional knapsack are independent as far as I know.

**My question**: How is my problem called and what are possible solutions? I know it has to be studied because every warehouse has this problem :) maybe I should not look for a combinatorial but a geometric approximation?

*Update*: Items can be rotated in any way. But to keep it simple I would like to restrain the rotation by 90 degrees in any direction. Moreover every item is a box and does not have holes which can be filled by other items.

Comment: Can we twist boxes to put them into container?

Comment: Thanks for your input @restrest, I updated my question accordingly

Comment: try to google "3 dimensional knapsack problem", I think that's what you need

Answer (score 1):

It can be considered as a set-covering problem.
 For each set $S$ of items that can fit in a box, let $c(S)$ be the cost of the
cheapest box that can contain $S$. 
Then you want to solve the integer linear programming problem

minimize $\sum_S c(S) x_S$

subject to

$\sum_{S: \; i \in S} x_S = 1$ for all items $i$

all $x_S \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: But that doesn't contain the problem description of how to find out whether or not a set `S` of items fits into the box?

Comment: That part of it is easy, if there are only a small number of items.  If there are too many items to enumerate all
the possible sets, you might try "column generation" as in the Cutting Stock problem.